# Create DynamoDB through custom resources Cloud Formation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a GlobalTable in AWS DynamoDB with the below Cloud formation template script. However I am not sure if I have all things required.
My Custom Resource section looks like below.

```
     "CreateGlobalTable":{  
      "Type":"Custom::CreateGlobalTable",
      "Properties":{  
        "ServiceToken":{  
          "Fn::GetAtt":[  
            "SolutionHelper",
            "Arn"
          ]
        },

         "GlobalTableName": "myglobaltable",
           "ReplicationGroup": [ 
              { 
                 "RegionName": "eu-west-1"
              }
           ]
      }
    },
```

When the stack is generated I see an entry for the same in the logs, however no Global table is created. Does it need a backing lamda function which will actually create the global table? or AWS API handles it automatically from the way it is defined above. Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you actually need to have a Lambda function that does the actual creation/update/deletion of the GlobalTable.

Here's a basic guidance on how to proceed:

```
  GlobalTableCustomResourceLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: global_table_custom_resource.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt CustomResourceRole.Arn
      Code: cloudformation/custom-resource/global_table_custom_resource.py
      Runtime: python3.6
      Timeout: '25'

  CustomResourceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Sid: ''
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: GlobalTableCustomResourceLambdaPolicy
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - dynamodb:CreateTable
            - dynamodb:UpdateTable
            - dynamodb:DeleteTable
            Resource: "*"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
```

For the Python code, I think it's beyond the scope of a StackOverflow answer, I'll refer you to this article which goes through the whole process: https://serverlesscode.com/post/python-custom-resource-cloudformation/.